# ComboBox stops updating when clicked / opened

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a view with 2 `ComboBoxes`. When an item is selected in the first one, a list is get for the second one. The properties that link the view and view model are as follow:

In the code behind of the view I link the view and view model

```
var viewModel = new MetrologyFileViewModel();
DataContext = viewModel;
```

WPF:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MetrologyProperties}"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding NewSelectedMetrologyPropertyIndex}"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle1}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding NewMetrologyData}"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding NewSelectedMetrologyDataIndex}"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle1}" />
```

C#:

```
/// <summary>
/// The new metrology property of the metrology data.
/// </summary>
public int NewSelectedMetrologyPropertyIndex
{
    get { return _newSelectedMetrologyPropertyIndex; }
    set
    {
        _newSelectedMetrologyPropertyIndex = value;

        _newMetrologyData = _newSelectedMetrologyPropertyIndex > 0 ? new ObservableCollection<MetrologyData> { new MetrologyData() }.AddRange(DbServiceMetrologyData.GetOnProperty(MetrologyProperties[_newSelectedMetrologyPropertyIndex])) : null;

         NotifyPropertyChanged();
         NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(NewMetrologyData));
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The new available metrology data that can be chosen from.
/// </summary>
public ObservableCollection<MetrologyData> NewMetrologyData
{
    get { return _newMetrologyData; }
    set
    {
        _newMetrologyData = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The new metrology data of the metrology fie.
/// </summary>
public int NewSelectedMetrologyDataIndex
{
    get { return _newSelectedMetrologyDataIndex; }
    set
    {
        _newSelectedMetrologyDataIndex = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The `AddRange` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Add a range of items to a <see cref="ObservableCollection{T}"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the <see cref="ObservableCollection{T}"/></typeparam>
/// <param name="sourceCollection">The <see cref="ObservableCollection{T}"/> where the items have to be added to.</param>
/// <param name="newCollection"><see cref="ObservableCollection{T}"/> with the new items.</param>
    public static ObservableCollection<T> AddRange<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> sourceCollection, ObservableCollection<T> newCollection)
{
    if (newCollection != null)
        foreach (var item in newCollection)
            sourceCollection.Add(item);

    return sourceCollection;
}
```

The first time I select a property in the 1st `ComboBox`, the 2nd one updates fine though the view (I think) isn't fully updated because the space where the list should be displayed is very small (see picture).

This keeps working as long as I don't click the 2nd `ComboBox`. From the moment I open (click on) the 2nd `ComboBox`, it stops updating when I select a property in the 1st one.

[image]

[image]

---

**Update**
I found out that when just calling `DbServiceMetrologyData.GetOnProperty(MetrologyProperties[_newSelectedMetrologyPropertyIndex])` the problem is fixed, I don't know why though.

Comment: If you have found the answer then please close your question then

Comment: It is not good practice to put logic in the MVVM property setters, you should implement SelectionChangedCommand handler for the combobox and handle this in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that when just calling `DbServiceMetrologyData.GetOnProperty(MetrologyProperties[_newSelectedMetrologyPropertyIndex])` the problem is fixed, I don't know why though.